# Is reassigning to the same string variable with nextLine() a bad practice in Java?

Tags: java

I am learning about good practice for java coding. I usually see an example like below.
Strings are immutable so I assume the reassigning values to the same string variable could create another string object. 
I am a little bit confused.

Are codes below considered a bad practice? Doesn't it mean that the same string reference str point to the different objects and we could not access those objects anymore ? If this is true, should we have replace() method to avoid this situation ? Is it correct that we should just use different classes such as StringBuilder ? I only need some confirmation about my thoughts.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = null;
while( input.hasNext()){
 str = input.nextLine();
 System.out.println(str);
}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: No it's fine.  But in this case declaring `str` inside the loop would reduce its scope, which is generally considered good practice.

Comment: You're right--the second time you go through the loop and assign `str`, the `String` that got created the first time won't be accessible any more.  That's fine, because (1) you don't need it any more, and (2) the object won't be left cluttering up memory forever, because Java has a _garbage collector_ that will eventually reuse the memory for objects that aren't used any more.

Comment: Basically, this is the 100% normal way to do things in memory-managed languages like Java or C#.  If you're writing programs to be run on systems with very limited memory and/or that have to be highly optimized, then you might want to use a different language.

Comment: I prefer to declare such variable outside of a loop. 1) debugger window does not change existing variables while looping through the cycle (my convenience) 2) variable does not need to be allocated each cycle (probably over-optimization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More or less it is fine to use the same variable to scan an input through nextLine() (or any similar method). But I agree with @markspace comment that `str` should have been defined inside the loop if you do not intend to use it outside of the loop. And yes, since you lose the reference to your old String so you will not be able to access it any more and Garbage Collector will clear it off the memory once it finds that there are no incoming pointers to that variable. But that is fine in your case since you do not require to do any processing on the old value any more.

In short, if you want to use that value sometime in future then you will need to store in different variable or an Array or something similar, else you can use the same variable to hold the value and do not care about the old values.